# How to use a shared react widget components in other react portlets - Liferay 7.4

Tags: reactjs, liferay-7, liferay-7.4

I have a requirement where I need to create reusable components in React and use them in other react portlets in Liferay.

Here are the steps I tried:

I have a react widget (reusable widget) and react portlet (consuming portlet)

1. reusable widget:

   ReusableComponent.js

   ```
   import React from 'react';

   const ReusableComponent = () => {
     return <div>This is a reusable React component.</div>;
   };

   export default ReusableComponent;
   ```
2. Import the component in other Portlets like:

   Portlet1.js

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReusableComponent from '../../reusable-component/src/main/resources/jsx/ReusableComponent';

   const Portlet1 = () => {
     return (
       <div>
         <h2>Portlet 1</h2>
         <ReusableComponent />
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default Portlet1;
   ```
3. Here is my .babelrc

   ```
   {
     "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
     "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
   }
   ```

After I deployed I'm getting errors like: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Exports is not defined" and then "Liferay-am-loader . A require call has failed in loader.js", missing dependencies.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Can someone suggest to me how to implement the same?

Answer (score 0):

in the project of portlet1.js you should have an file .npmbundlerrc if not just create it and the import of the widget project

```
{
    
    "config": {
        "imports": {
            "reusable-component": {         
                "reusable-component": "^1.0.0"          
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

after you have instert the import you can call the import like this way

```
import ReusableComponent from 'reusable-component/jsx/ReusableComponent';
```

You can do the same think with liferay components or dipendencies just adding the import like this way  in the example below the react and react-dom so to have same version as liferay

```
   {
        "config": {
            "imports": {
                "reusable-component": {         
                    "reusable-component": "^1.0.0"          
                },
                "@liferay/frontend-js-react-web": {             
                    "react": "*",
                    "react-dom": "*"
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```